# Function already defined line, Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} got kicked :cry:")
    await ctx.send("https://giphy.com/gifs/warnerarchive-warner-archive-blaxploitation-melinda-l3V0j3ytFyGHqiV7W")

@kick.error
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("incorrect command")
```

This is my code for the kick function, and i get this error "function already defined". When I run the program in Visual Studio Code runs perfectly but i receive this error.

Comment: Do you have another function named `kick` or `on_command_error`?

Comment: Yes, also ban command and error.